# Visual Studio Isolated Shell Toolbox not being updated after uninstall/install of new package version

Tags: visual-studio, dsl

I am developing a DSL package that has a number of toolbar items.  If I add a new toolbar item in the DSL explorer install the new package into the Visual Studio isolated shell the new items don't appear.  I am testing this on a virtual machine first by installing the first version of the package, uninstalling it and then installing the updated version.  It seems that the system is somehow caching the old toolbar settings, etc even though a new version of the DSL package assembly is being installed.

Any ideas why the old tool bar items appear and the new ones don't?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, a cache mechanism is used. The problem doesn't appear if you use a new account to launch your shell.
I don't know the reasons why this problem occurs but here is a workaround to force the toolbox refresh.

- Go to USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\AppEnv\Apps\YourShell_GUID\
- Remove all tbd files (.tbd) (Don't forget that tbd files are hidden files).

Good luck.